# How to connect NexusDB in windows via python?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, nexusdb

Does anyone have any idea about connecting to NexusDB via python? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

NexusDB does not currently have direct support for Python, but are considering it for future feature additions. Right now your best bet would be to connect via ODBC.

Comment: successfully connected via NexusDB ODBC connector and pyodbc. eagerly waiting for the python addition.